# How can we set analytics.js cookies after user confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

With GDPR coming into force, we wanted to restrict our application from dropping any cookie until the user confirms his/her consent.

To do this, I have disabled the analytics on page load by using the following config.

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXXXX-X'] = true;
```

After user gives consent by clicking on the cookie banner, I have to enable tracking.

Theoretically, I have to enable it by adding the below line after user action.

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXXXX-X'] = false;
```

and run the analytics.js again which i am not sure how to.

I have found a solution for the legacy ga.js but not for analytics.js.

Is there any other way of doing this which i am missing?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is widely used is the use of a cookie message. This message can be fired by Google Tag Manager or a snippet from a tool (for example Cookiebot) that is hard coded on your website. Since Google Tag Manager does not collect any PII you can use it without any permission. When the cookie message has fired you can collect a cookie when they give explicit permission. Collect this cookie within Google Tag Manager as a variable. When you want to send data for example to Google Analytics (tag) you can set a trigger which has certain constraints. for example send a pageview (tag) when someone hit a pageview (trigger) and has given permission (variable).

Comment: _you can use it without any permission_ - not true.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at how Google Tag Manager does it, might help or could even use GTM.

To implement Google Tag Manager on your website:

Copy the following JavaScript and paste it as close to the opening  tag as possible on every page of your website, replacing GTM-XXXX with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Copy the following snippet and paste it immediately after the opening  tag on every page of your website, replacing GTM-XXXX with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Many tag management operations can be achieved by just doing the basic code installation, but if you'd like to have finer grain control over tag events or data, you may want to use some customization using our asynchronous methods.